# To parse an xml having attributes

Tags: android, android-parser

```
 <content type="xhtml">

        <apxh:div>
            <apxh:p>xyz</apxh:p>
            <apxh:p>xyz</apxh:p>
            <apxh:p>xyz</apxh:p>
            <apxh:p>xyz</apxh:p>
            <apxh:p>xyz</apxh:p>

        </apxh:div>
    </content>
```

I am able to get the "xhtml" present in type by,

```
       item.getChild(url,CONTENT).setStartElementListener(new StartElementListener() {

        @Override
        public void start(Attributes attributes) {
        str=attributes.getValue("type");


        }
    });
    item.getChild(url,CONTENT).setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {

        @Override
        public void end() {
            currentMessage.setType(str);

        }
    });
```

Now how can i get the "apxh:div" as it is separated by ":"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to parse it for SOAP parsing.
The tag patterns of ur Xml shows that, try out using Soap parsing 
surely help you...

Comment: Actually it's an atom feed parsing.